# null reference object not set to reference of an object on a label.text property

Tags: c#, windows, forms, nullreferenceexception

I have been racking my brain (not hard to do) trying to figure this exception out. I have a form that display's user information. When I set breakpoints and step through the code. The method call returns the object (checked in the immediate window) but when I assign the user property to the label is when this occurs.

Here is my code:

```
public Form2()
        {
            UserInfo user = FileAccess.UserInfoFromXML();
            // All the members of user exist.
            label1.Text = "Screen Name: " + user.ScreenName; //This is throwing an Null Reference exception the UserInfo is not null
            label2.Text = "Full Name: "+ user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
            label3.Text = "Address: " + user.StreetAddress + " " + user.City + " " + user.State + " " + user.Zip;
            label4.Text = "Email Address: " + user.email;
            label5.Text = "Date Of Birth: " + user.DateOfBirth;
            label6.Text = "Start Date: " + user.StartDate;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse( user.StartDate );
            dt.AddDays( 30 );
            label7.Text = "End Date: " + dt.ToShortDateString();

        }
```

Any ideas?
Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to let the `InitializeComponent()` call stay on top of the constructor.

This designer-generated method initializes your components so the labels won't be `null` anymore when you access them.

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank You. I will mark this as an answer in a few min.